# How to pause IOCP TCP socket server?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, winsock, iocp

My program is similar to a HTTP proxy, it waits for messages on an interface and it forwards them to another interface. The application uses only IOCP, both client and server sides. Sometimes, the client is slower (in a ratio of 10 or 100) than the server, which can not buffering too much data.
How can I suspend an established TCP connection then resume it without losing any message? I tried to delay the post of a new recv IOCP event, but some messages are lost.
C++/Windows 7+

Comment: Negotiate a smaller sliding window size, equal to the amount of data you are willing to buffer on a single connection.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to delay the post of a new recv IOCP event

That should in fact do the trick. Your server side TCP connection's receive buffer would then fill up to the receive buffer size as set on your socket, at which point the socket will push back to the sending side of that socket, which - by standard means of [TCP flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) - simply stops sending more packets until the receiver signals having processed more messages.

Now it depends on the sending side how long it wants to wait (timeout), before disconnecting.

> "some messages are lost"

That can only happen with TCP if you get disconnected, which both the sender and the receiver will take notice of. So data isn't simply lost. It depends on your network protocol on top of TCP though whether the sender application can know how much of the messages the receiving application (your proxy, in this case) successfully processed.

Comment: Thanks, the behavior of the TCP stack when posts are delayed wasn't clear to me.